# vuejs: Update computed property when nested data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a computed property which relies on a data object updating to perform a calculation and return the value. The computed property updates whenever the first level of nesting is updated, however the computed property does not update when nested data props of the base object are updated.

I have provided the code samples below. Essentially the problem occurs when the nested properties of `this.form.business_details.usage` are updated. To elaborate, when `this.form.business_details.quote_type` updates, `this.completion.business_details.quote_type` also updates as the latter is dependent on the former.

However when `this.form.business_details.usage.spend_type` updates, the computed prop for `completion()` is not re-evaluated. Do computed properties not watch nested data by default? If not, how can I trigger an update?

```
<script>
import Form from '@/classes/Form';
import { filter, map, snakeCase } from 'lodash';

export default {
  name: 'Form',

  computed: {
    completion() {
      return {
        business_details: {
          postcode: this.generateFormCompletionObject(true, this.form.business_details.postcode),
          quote_type: this.generateFormCompletionObject(true, this.form.business_details.quote_type),
          current_supplier: this.generateFormCompletionObject(true, this.form.business_details.current_supplier),
          knows_usage: this.generateFormCompletionObject(true, this.form.business_details.knows_usage, true),
          usage: {
            spend_type: this.generateFormCompletionObject(
              typeof this.form.business_details.knows_usage === 'boolean' && this.form.business_details.knows_usage,
              typeof this.form.business_details.knows_usage === 'boolean' && this.form.business_details.spend_type
            ),
            billing_period: this.generateFormCompletionObject(
              typeof this.form.business_details.knows_usage === 'boolean' && this.form.business_details.knows_usage,
              typeof this.form.business_details.knows_usage === 'boolean' && this.form.business_details.billing_period
            ),
            amount: this.generateFormCompletionObject(
              typeof this.form.business_details.knows_usage === 'boolean' && this.form.business_details.knows_usage,
              typeof this.form.business_details.knows_usage === 'boolean' && this.form.business_details.amount
            ),
          },
        },
      };
    },

    completionPercentage() {      
      const required = this.recursiveCompletionCheck(Object.values(this.completion.business_details))
        .flat()
        .filter(value => value)
        .map(value => +!! value.given);

      return required.filter(value => value).length / required.length * 100;
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      completed: {
        business_details: false,
        personal_details: false,
      },
      form: new Form({
        business_details: {
          postcode: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('postcode') || null,
          quote_type: null,
          current_supplier: null,
          knows_usage: null,
          usage: {
            spend_type: null,
            billing_period: null,
            amount: null,
          },
        },
        personal_details: {
          full_name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null,
          email_consent: false,
        },
      }),
    };
  },

  methods: {
    generateFormCompletionObject(required, key, requiresBoolean = false) {
      return {
        required: required,
        given: requiresBoolean
          ? typeof key === 'boolean' 
          : !! key,
      };    
    },

    recursiveCompletionCheck(values) {
      return values.map(value => {
        if ('required' in value && value.required) return value;
        if ('required' in value && !value.required) return null;

        if (!! Object.keys(value).length) {
          return recursiveCompletionChecker(Object.values(value));
        }

        return null;
      });
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested object properties aren't automatically re-evaluated. You can watch for its changes with `watch`. [Here is the documentation for more info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch). The relevant part you need is:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    foo() { return this.item.foo; }
  },
  watch: {
    foo() { console.log('Foo Changed!'); }
  },
  data: {
    item: { foo: 'foo' }
  }
})
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/threenuc/pen/XWgXBRv I think this answer is incorrect. The reactivity caveats mentioned by Vue are only - adding a new object property that doesn't exist and updating something by array index. The link you've provided doesn't mention any nesting caveats