# Does Vue recalculate computed property if nested data is updated?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961063/vuejs-update-computed-property-when-nested-data-changes) mentions that updated properties don't get updated if a nested object is updated. Is that true?
Can't find much in this [guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties).

In this example:

```
data() {
    return {
        example: [
          { 
           myArray : ['foo1', 'bar1'] 
           myObject: {
               "foo2": "bar2",
               "foo3": {
                    "foo4": "bar4"
          }
        ]
    },
computed: {
    sameExample() {
        return this.example
    }
}
```

would any of the changes to the nested data of example trigger Vue to recalculate the property?

Answer (score 1):

The old answer is true for Vue 2, but for Vue 3 those reactivity caveats have been resolved, so you could update nested data and it will reevaluate the computed property as shown below :

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {

  data() {
    return {
      example: [{
        myArray: ['foo1', 'bar1'],
        myObject: {
          "foo2": "bar2",
          "foo3": {
            "foo4": "bar4"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sameExample() {
      return this.example[0].myArray.join()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.example[0].myArray.push("test")
    }
  }



}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{sameExample}}

  <button @click="addItem">add item</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question/answer you're linking to is just wrong.

Vue 2 updates computeds when a nested property changes. This is NOT a reactivity caveat, because it works and it's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation together with any other reactivity caveats.

I changed Boussadjra's answer to Vue 2 here, and it works exactly the same.

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {

  data() {
    return {
      example: [{
        myArray: ['foo1', 'bar1'],
        myObject: {
          "foo2": "bar2",
          "foo3": {
            "foo4": "bar4"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sameExample() {
      return this.example[0].myArray.join()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.example[0].myArray.push("test")
    }
  }



}
const app = new Vue(App)
app.$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{sameExample}}

  <button @click="addItem">add item</button>
</div>
```